# Можно ли запретить ошибку получения картинки в консоле браузера?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который проверяет существование картинки (см. ниже) и если скажем файл реально существует мы помещаем картинку себе на сайт, если нет, ничего не делаем:

```js
var img1 = new Image(),
    img2 = new Image();
  
img1.src = 'https://images.noob-club.ru/news/2018/05/1vl4sul2bq.jpg';
img1.onload = function() {
    alert('Картинка существует, отлично, выводим ее');
};

img2.src = 'https://images.noob-club.ru/news/2018/05/1vl4sul2bq_.jpg';
img2.onerror = function() {
    alert('А вот 2-ой картинки нет на сервере, и видим ошибку в консоле браузера =(');
};
```

Однако, если картинки не существует, в консоле браузера мы видим ошибку GET запроса:

[image: Ошибка получения картинки GET запросом]

**Вопрос:** Как мне скрыть ошибку в консоле браузера, если файл не удалось загрузить?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем?

Comment: @andreymal Ну вот надо мне, может у кого есть какие идеи, а если никак не сделать, значит будет так всё работать.

Comment: Теоретически разработчики браузеров могли не добавить такую функцию, потому что тоже не поняли зачем :)

Comment: Вряд ли можно что-то с этим сделать, проще реализовать API, которое будет возвращать картинку или сообщение о ее отсутствии, которое вы можете уже самостоятельно обрабатывать.

Comment: Можно смотреть в другом браузере, например `IE6` - в нем нет консоли и не будет ошибки! А если серьезно, то если у вас хром, можете убрать показ ошибок сети, вот так http://prntscr.com/jnk9wo